# Gtk and gstreamer linker error

Tags: c++, gtk, gstreamer

I m trying to compile the simple [gst player](http://code.google.com/p/gst-player/) from google code. I have fixed and installed missing libraries now i m getting a linker error

```
vickey@tb:~/work/gst-player-0.0.0$ make
gcc -ggdb -Wall -W -Wformat-nonliteral -Wcast-align -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Winline -Wundef -Wnested-externs -Wcast-qual -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -Wfloat-equal -pedantic -ansi -std=c99 `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0` `pkg-config --cflags gstreamer-0.10` `pkg-config --libs gstreamer-0.10` -lgstinterfaces-0.10 ui.c gst-backend.c -o gst-player
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:236:0,
                 from ui.c:19:
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkitemfactory.h:47:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
ui.c: In function ‘toggle_fullscreen’:
ui.c:60:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gtk_window_unfullscreen’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwindow.h:340:10: note: expected ‘struct GtkWindow *’ but argument is of type ‘struct GtkWidget *’
ui.c:65:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gtk_window_fullscreen’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwindow.h:339:10: note: expected ‘struct GtkWindow *’ but argument is of type ‘struct GtkWidget *’
gst-backend.c: In function ‘backend_query_position’:
gst-backend.c:164:5: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 3 of ‘gst_element_query_position’ differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/gstutils.h:1047:25: note: expected ‘gint64 *’ but argument is of type ‘guint64 *’
gst-backend.c: In function ‘backend_query_duration’:
gst-backend.c:177:5: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 3 of ‘gst_element_query_duration’ differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/gstutils.h:1049:25: note: expected ‘gint64 *’ but argument is of type ‘guint64 *’
/tmp/cckH1GSv.o: In function `toggle_paused':
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:43: undefined reference to `gtk_button_get_type'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:43: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:43: undefined reference to `gtk_button_set_label'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:49: undefined reference to `gtk_button_get_type'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:49: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:49: undefined reference to `gtk_button_set_label'
/tmp/cckH1GSv.o: In function `toggle_fullscreen':
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:60: undefined reference to `gtk_window_unfullscreen'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:65: undefined reference to `gtk_window_fullscreen'
/tmp/cckH1GSv.o: In function `destroy':
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:96: undefined reference to `gtk_main_quit'
/    tmp/cckH1GSv.o: In function `key_press':
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:127: undefined reference to `gtk_main_quit'
/tmp/cckH1GSv.o: In function `start':
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:167: undefined reference to `gtk_window_new'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:169: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:169: undefined reference to `g_signal_connect_data'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:172: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:172: undefined reference to `g_signal_connect_data'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:175: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:175: undefined reference to `g_signal_connect_data'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:178: undefined reference to `gtk_container_get_type'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:178: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:178: undefined reference to `gtk_container_set_border_width'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:180: undefined reference to `gtk_vbox_new'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:182: undefined reference to `gtk_container_get_type'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:182: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:182: undefined reference to `gtk_container_add'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:184: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_show'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:186: undefined reference to `gtk_hbox_new'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:188: undefined reference to `gtk_box_get_type'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:188: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:188: undefined reference to `gtk_box_pack_end'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:190: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_show'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:193: undefined reference to `gtk_drawing_area_new'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:195: undefined reference to `gtk_box_get_type'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:195: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:195: undefined reference to `gtk_box_pack_start'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:197: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_set_size_request'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:199: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_show'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:203: undefined reference to `gtk_button_new_with_label'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:205: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:205: undefined reference to `g_signal_connect_data'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:208: undefined reference to `gtk_box_get_type'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:208: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:208: undefined reference to `gtk_box_pack_start'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:210: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_show'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:216: undefined reference to `gtk_button_new_with_label'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:218: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:218: undefined reference to `g_signal_connect_data'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:221: undefined reference to `gtk_box_get_type'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:221: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:221: undefined reference to `gtk_box_pack_start'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:223: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_show'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:228: undefined reference to `gtk_adjustment_new'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:229: undefined reference to `gtk_adjustment_get_type'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:229: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:229: undefined reference to `gtk_hscale_new'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:231: undefined reference to `gtk_box_get_type'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:231: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:231: undefined reference to `gtk_box_pack_end'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:233: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:233: undefined reference to `g_signal_connect_data'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:236: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_show'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:239: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_show'
/tmp/cckH1GSv.o: In function `init':
/    home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:245: undefined reference to `gdk_x11_drawable_get_xid'
/tmp/cckH1GSv.o: In function `timeout':
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:275: undefined reference to `gtk_range_get_type'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:275: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:275: undefined reference to `gtk_range_set_value'
/tmp/cckH1GSv.o: In function `main':
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:285: undefined reference to `gtk_init'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:293: undefined reference to `g_strdup'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:295: undefined reference to `g_strdup_printf'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:299: undefined reference to `g_idle_add'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:300: undefined reference to `g_timeout_add'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:302: undefined reference to `gtk_main'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/ui.c:304: undefined reference to `g_free'
/tmp/cc9cDvJS.o: In function `bus_cb':
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:39: undefined reference to `g_log'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:47: undefined reference to `gst_message_parse_error'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:48: undefined reference to `g_free'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:50: undefined reference to `g_log'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:51: undefined reference to `g_error_free'
/tmp/cc9cDvJS.o: In function `backend_init':
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:65: undefined reference to `gst_init'
/tmp/cc9cDvJS.o: In function `backend_play':
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:79: undefined reference to `gst_pipeline_new'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:81: undefined reference to `gst_element_factory_make'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:82: undefined reference to `gst_element_factory_make'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:84: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:84: undefined reference to `g_object_set'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:86: undefined reference to `gst_bin_get_type'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:86: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:86: undefined reference to `gst_bin_add'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:90: undefined reference to `gst_pipeline_get_type'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:90: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:90: undefined reference to `gst_pipeline_get_bus'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:91: undefined reference to `gst_bus_add_watch'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:92: undefined reference to `gst_object_unref'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:95: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:95: undefined reference to `g_object_set'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:97: undefined reference to `gst_x_overlay_get_type'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:97: undefined reference to `gst_implements_interface_check'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:99: undefined reference to `gst_x_overlay_get_type'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:99: undefined reference to `gst_implements_interface_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:99: undefined reference to `gst_x_overlay_set_xwindow_id'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:102: undefined reference to `gst_element_set_state'
/tmp/cc9cDvJS.o: In function `backend_stop':
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:110: undefined reference to `gst_element_set_state'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:111: undefined reference to `gst_object_get_type'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:111: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:111: undefined reference to `gst_object_unref'
/tmp/cc9cDvJS.o: In function `backend_pause':
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:119: undefined reference to `gst_element_set_state'
/tmp/cc9cDvJS.o: In function `backend_resume':
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:125: undefined reference to `gst_element_set_state'
/tmp/cc9cDvJS.o: In function `backend_reset':
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:131: undefined reference to `gst_element_seek'
/tmp/cc9cDvJS.o: In function `backend_seek':
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:141: undefined reference to `gst_element_seek'
/tmp/cc9cDvJS.o: In function `backend_seek_absolute':
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:151: undefined reference to `gst_element_seek'
/tmp/cc9cDvJS.o: In function `backend_query_position':
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:164: undefined reference to `gst_element_query_position'
/tmp/cc9cDvJS.o: In function `backend_query_duration':
/home/vickey/work/gst-player-0.0.0/gst-backend.c:177: undefined reference to `gst_element_query_duration'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [gst-player] Error 1
```

I think I might be missing some library imports but I am not able to figure out . Thanks

Comment: What does the command `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0` print?

Comment: -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0

Comment: Hmm, looks fine to me. Where is `libgtk-x11-2.0.so`? What does the command "`nm -D /path/to/libgtk-x11-2.0.so | grep gtk_button_get_type`" show? (Obviously, you have to substitute the path to `libgtk-x11-2.0.so`.)

Comment: @MichaelWild: Here is the output for the command. 
`vickey@tb:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ nm -D libgtk-x11-2.0.so|grep 
gtk_button_get_type 


000000000008cc90 T gtk_button_get_type
`  As pointed out in the solution below the source file was specified after the libraries . It compiles fine when source files are mentioned before the libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem most likely because the linker is not linking against the library until it see any symbol from the library in the compilation, as the source appears after the linking to libraries while compiling. As the linker will not link against a library until it encounters a symbol in the library from the source, you will need to move the source at the beginning of compilation command. Currently the `Makefile` provide in the source link builds as follows:

```
 19 gst-player: ui.c gst-backend.c
 20     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(GTK_LIBS) $(GST_CFLAGS) $(GST_LIBS) $+ -o $@
```

Change that to :

```
 19 gst-player: ui.c gst-backend.c
 20     $(CC) $+ $(CFLAGS) $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(GTK_LIBS) $(GST_CFLAGS) $(GST_LIBS) -o $@
```

(Note that now the sources are right after `$(CC)`). Alternatively, you can ask the linker to link the libraries irrespectively of encountering the symbols from the library using `-Wl, --no-as-needed` option. In that case, `Makefile` changes might look like this:

```
 19 gst-player: ui.c gst-backend.c
 20     $(CC) -Wl,--no-as-needed $(CFLAGS) $(GTK_CFLAGS) $(GTK_LIBS) $(GST_CFLAGS) $(GST_LIBS) $+ -o $@
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great it worked ! :D . But sadly its not running though compiling properly.

 `vickey@tb:~/work/gst-player-0.0.0$ ./gst-player Opening_Music.ogg 
** (gst-player:8342): WARNING **: Error: Could not open resource for reading.

`

The file works fine with MPlayer. I wonder what might be the problem now .

Comment: Thank you another.anon.coward! You save me a lot of time! But I have some questions for Vihaan Verma. I use gstreamer 1.0 and I refactored code a little bit. Does it player works after compilation and linking? I have error looks like didn't load media source etc...